# How to configure DNS for instances on aws?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, amazon-ec2

I have 3 instances running on amazon ec2

instance 1 should be called myname.com,
instance 2 and 3 should be called node1.myname.com and node2.myname.com respectively.
How can this be achieved ? (can this be achieved ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Route 53 is a option but is nothing like a easy solution. Amazon DNS is painful. You will need to write a script to dynamically update the dns to match what you want.

There is a whole bunch of other DNS services like zerigo ou dyndns that accept either REST calls to change the DNS or have a tool to automatically update the DNS.

Painful, but the only way. Another solution is to use Elastic IP's, but they are limited to 5 per region.

If you have a Elastic IP you can even request to have amazon resolve their reverse DNS for that IP. It is especially useful when you need to have a mail server.

Comment: Did you figure this out?